# Which word best describes the state just before a person is about to sleep?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonyms

I am looking for a word that describes the state just before a person slips into sleep. I am not talking about the state when the person is inactive or sedentary, but specifically in reference to sleep. The last two minutes before you go out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of being *almost* asleep is sometimes referred to as "dozing" or "dozing off".

Example:

> "He was just dozing off when a noise startled him".